# JTable coloring?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable with 4 columns.  A user populates this table with their information.  Once the user is done populating the table, there is a button they can select which will display an entry box and enter some criteria that will then match against what they entered in the jtable.  My question is how can I color the text of each row based on the criteria the user enters.  If the criteria matches any of the lines in the jtable they entered, I want to turn the text in the row green, and for the rows that don't match the criteria, I want those to turn the text red.  I can't seem to find any examples with that specific use case in terms of using renderers.  Any help would be great and thank you in advance.

Comment: Check out [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/). It shows how to color a row based on a hard data value in the row. You would need to modify the code to do the color based on a variable containing the text you want to search for. Once the text is entered in the text field you will need to repaint() the entire table.

Comment: *"If the criteria matches any of the lines in the jtable they entered, I want to turn the text in the row green, and for the rows that don't match the criteria, I want those to turn the text red."* Consider using a [`RowSorter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/RowSorter.html) instead. IF you want to stick to the red / green approach, implement the logic in the renderer. BTW - *"JTable coloring?"* Is not a question just because it has `?` on the end of it. What *is* your question?